# Pentaho metastore location when connecting to repository

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am configuring the repository to work with Pentaho. Currently I have a simple script that creates some Environmental variables (e.g. KETTLE_HOME) and then calls/opens the provided spoon client.

Here is how I am calling the spoon client:

```
set OPT="-DPENTAHO_METASTORE_FOLDER=%KETTLE_META_HOME%" %OPT%
call  %KETTLE_CLIENT_DIR%\Spoon.bat %OPT% %*
```

KETTLE_META_HOME is something like "PATH/TO/PROJECT/config/local-config"
With this command, when spoon opens and I navigate to VSF Connections (for example) I can see the metastore files under PATH/TO/PROJECT/config/local-config/metastore, as desired.

The problem occurs when I connect to a repository (file based, not sure if relevant), as it creates a folder PATH/TO/PROJECT/.meta/metastore and simply reads/writes there instead...

The repository configuration is stored under PATH/TO/PROJECT/config/local-config/.kettle/repositories.xml and the base_directory is PATH/TO/PROJECT.

So my question is how can I keep using my PATH/TO/PROJECT/config/local-config/metastore even when connecting to the repository?

I tried setting the metastore folder in different ways, including within the kettle.properties file, however the problem still occurs.

Comment: Do you really need to use a repository to run PDI? Is there a specific reason to use it? You can run PDI without using a repository, just indicating the files locations (you can use relative paths and variables so it's easier to move between machines and enviroments) If you are using the Community Edition of Pentaho Data Integration it makes more sense, repositories weren't optimized for the CE edition, so you run into a lot of complications that are not needed really.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I am forced to use a repository. This was decided to promote collaboration in the group.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your comment. You probably meant that we can simply run spoon without connecting to a repository. If so, yes we could certainly do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only reason to use Pentaho repository is to promote collaboration, I think it's better not to use Pentaho own repository and work with git or your source control system for collaboration.

After all, PDI transformations and jobs are XML files so it's easy to use those version control systems. You have variables like `${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}` for relative paths, or you can use your own variable.

You can also work with a couple of plugins available in Github to use environments so changing configurations is easier: http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2018/12/16/Kettle-Environment.html
The plugins aren't maintained, they were developed for PDI 8.2, but I think they still work, since Hitachi Vantara hasn't been making major changes to the code base.

Comment: I looked at these environment plugins and I am a bit confused by how they interact with KETTLE_HOME. 

So they allow you to define different environments, which are stored in your .kettle folder (so usually in the user's home). So in my case, I would still need a script to set the KETTLE_HOME to the project's folder, correct?
Another thing are the database and VSF Connections. These are stored in the .kettle/shared.xml or metastore folder. These will be the same for all environments, right? If so, should we parametrize them and use different variables? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You use variables and define the same variables with different values for each environment. For example, you have a connection to a MariaDB database, you define the connection in PDI as usual, but instead of putting the host name, DB name, port, user and password, you use variables: ${MARIADB_HOST}, ${MARIADB_PORT}, ${MARIADB_DBNAME}, ${MARIADB_USER}, ${MARIADB_PWD}, then you define two environments: ENV_DEV and ENV_PRO, both environments have the same variables: MARIADB_HOST, MARIADB_PORT, MARIADB_DBNAME, MARIADB_USER and MARIADB_PWD, but the value is different pointing to a different DB.

Comment: You can also create variables for the different paths, but if you only need a path, you can use the pre-built variable in the environment: ENVIRONMENT_HOME. In my case, but does how I use them, you can define it as you need, I use the ENVIRONMENT_HOME variable to define the top folder for my transformations and jobs (the project folder in git), and I've created another variable pointing to a different path for files I create or read in my jobs/transformations.

Comment: Anyway, if you aren't yet too invested in PDI, I would take a look to apache-hop. PDI was bought by Hitachi Vantara and hasn't evolved a lot since, and they killed the community where you could get help. Former developers of PDI leaded by Matt Caster, the creator of the environments and many other plugins (and a lot of the Kettle (previous name of PDI) code) took the open source code of PDI 8.2, cleaned it up, evolved it, updated libraries, and moved it under apache license. The starting point between hop and PDI is similar, but apache-hop has been given a lot of much attention lately.